# Android Revoke Permissions when App is running - Can I recover the App

Tags: android, permissions

I have just moved my target SDK to v9.

I have hit the issue where when I have my app running, I open the settings and revoke one of the permissions. When I then bring my app to the foreground it restarts and tries to restore the app, however it fails to restore properly.

My understanding is the behaviour should be the same as rotating the device. However in this case my app can recover correctly.

What the behaviour is when revoking permission when the app is running? Should the app just terminate and start from the beginning, or is it possible to recover?

Answer (score 5):

> My understanding the behaviour should be the same as rotating the device.

No.

> Can someone tell me what the behaviour is when revoking a permission when the app is running.

Your app's processes are terminated. Android will start a fresh process for your app when the user returns to it. Android *may* attempt to restart the last activity the user was in, depending on the timing of all of these events.

In general, the behavior is the same as if the user left your app for a while (say, 20 minutes), Android terminated the process in the background, and then the user returned to it.

> Should the app just terminate and the just start from the beginning, or is it possible to recover.

We cannot answer that, as the details will depend on the app. Ideally, your app can "recover", but it will require you to design the app to be able to deal with a fresh process from every activity.

Comment: So will the Bundle passed to my Activities OnCreate, OnSaveInstanceState and OnRestoreInstanceState be empty at this point?

Comment: @rideintothesun: Whether that `Bundle` is empty depends on whether you put anything in it and how long it has been since the user left your app. If the user left your app recently, Android will attempt to restart your last activity with the last saved instance state `Bundle`. There are strange edge cases where that may not work (e.g., multi-window, where your app's window was still up when the user revoked the permission in Settings).

Comment: Thankyou that has been really helpful. From what you say when the app is terminated it may or may not have the contents of the bundle that had been saved. The chances are if it is relatively quickly there is a chance it can restore properly as the bundle is likely to exist. I think my orientation is behaving differently because I have set android:configChanges for orientation

Comment: Could you add source to this information? "Your app's processes are terminated. Android will start a fresh process..."

Comment: @musclebananas: Most of this stuff is not documented, if that is what you are asking. However, it has behaved that way on every device I have tested, since runtime permissions were introduced.